# JSON.stringify reversal?

Tags: javascript, json

i have some arrays and js objects put into a string using `JSON.stringify`

how can i decode that string again into arrays and objects ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) lets you do that.

You can see plenty of examples everywhere on the Intarwebs.

Even jQuery has a shim for this method (not supported in IE6, maybe 7): [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). That is, if you use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

That would be:

```
JSON.parse
```

cheers
Dom

Answer (score 0):

You could use the eval method, or, much better, use JSON.parse. Please check this link for more info: http://www.json.org/js.html